# How to get http request header info from the server side with spray RestAPI

Tags: scala, spray, spray-test

I am new to Scala and Spray. I have written a simple REST API according to the instructions given in this blog post.
http://www.smartjava.org/content/first-steps-rest-spray-and-scala

And all are working as expected.

Now I want to modify the program to print the HTTP headers like Encoding, Language, remote-address, etc.. I would like to print all the header information (purpose is to log these information)

But I could not find a proper documentation or examples. Could anyone please help me to get this done.

Comment: Hi, Still I could not find a way to print all the http headers. In java we can get it as a collection and looping through it and print all. `I am just wondering why it is so hard with spray and scala ???`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to extract a specific header:

```
optionalHeaderValueByName("Encoding") { encodingHeader =>
  println(encodingHeader)
  complete("hello")
}
```

alternatively you can access the raw request object and directly extractive the headers. Here's a custom directive that logs all the headers:

```
def logHeaders(): Directive0 = extract(_.request.headers).map(println)
```

Usage

```
logHeaders() {
  complete("hello")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. For me the first way is working. But I would prefer the alternative way, and it gives a syntax error with calling 'foreach' -------Error:(37, 61) value foreach is not a member of spray.routing.Directive1[List[spray.http.HttpHeader]]
  def logHeaders(): Directive0 = extract(_.request.headers).foreach(println)---------

Comment: woops, try `map` instead of `foreach`

Comment: map does not help either. I get compilation error as -------Error:(42, 51) value foreach is not a member of spray.routing.Directive1[List[spray.http.HttpHeader]]
  def logHeaders1() =  extract(_.request.headers).foreach(println)----- The above is the error I got, unfortunately I couldn't get the list from spray.routing.Directive1

Comment: How can you have a `foreach` error if you're using `map`?

Comment: map didn't do anything for me. So Still I am struggling with foreach. Is map work for you ?

Comment: if I can get the `List[spray.http.HttpHeader]` from the `spray.routing.Directive1[List[spray.http.HttpHeader]]`, I will be able to use `foreach`. How can I get something out from `spray.routing.Directive1`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I got it working.

Directive:

```
def logHeaders(innerRoute: Route): (RequestContext => Unit) = extract(_.request.headers) { headers =>
  headers.foreach(h => logger.info("header: {} = {}", h.name, h.value))
  innerRoute
}
```

Usage:

```
logHeaders() {
  complete("hello")
}
```